# how to handle httpStatuscode correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-codes, jquery-1.5

I would like to react on http status-codes (like 200, 201 or 202) with the new feature (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax). But the function is ignoring my 201 and 202 callbacks.

This error occures with firefox-4.0_b10 and chromium-9.0

I'm looking forward to fix this little issue.

Regards Stefan

My code-snipped:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        statusCode: {
          404:function() { alert("404"); },
          200:function() { alert("200"); },
          201:function() { alert("201"); },
          202:function() { alert("202"); }
        },
        success: function(data){
          switch(data.status) {
            case 'done':
              /* display it to the User */
              break;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 201 and 202 responses as a result of the call you are testing with?  What you will want to do is either use fiddler or firebug to inspect the request and see what status code is being returned.  I suspect it is a 200 response as that is the success response for a GET or POST request

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the following:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        statusCode: {
          404:function() { alert("404"); },
          200:function() { alert("200"); },
          201:function() { alert("201"); },
          202:function() { alert("202"); }
        }/*,
        success: function(data){
          switch(data.status) {
            case 'done':
              /* display it to the User */
              break;
          }
        }*/
        });
```

Somehow, the success-method is in conflict with the httpStatusCode-Map

Regards Stefan

Comment: I had to spend a minute trying to figure out how your solution differed from the origin. Until I saw you had commented out the success function. If your solution really works, accept it as your own answer!