# Jquery: $ajax - error function called even on a successful request

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am sending an ajax request to an API (the instapaper one) and I have been able to make successful requests, i.e. I have postsed links to instapaper successfully and received the correct status code - 201.
However, the error callback function is called instead of the success one. I think this is because of the way that I have setup my request. E.g. it's is expecting the response in a different format.

The request function:

```
$("#instapaper").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url:'http://www.instapaper.com/api/add',
        data: {"url": ref , "username": "<%= current_user.instapaper_user %>", "password": "<%= current_user.instapaper_pass %>" },
        context: document.body,
        error: function() { 
          alert('There was an error!');
        },
        success: function() {
          alert('Page sent');
        },
      })
    });
```

I have tried using the status code callback for code 201, but that does not work either.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try catching the response if its a valid JSON using        `error: function(data) { 
          alert(data.responseText);
        }`

Comment: That's really weird given that according to the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) _"When data is retrieved from remote servers (which is only possible using the script or jsonp data types), the error callbacks and global events will never be fired."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [instapaper API](http://www.instapaper.com/api/simple#jsonp) takes `jsonp` as callback function name, but default in jQuery is `callback`.

I suggest you add `jsonp: 'jsonp'` to your ajax object and see if it works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url:'http://www.instapaper.com/api/add',
    data: {"url": ref , "username": "<%= current_user.instapaper_user %>", "password": "<%= current_user.instapaper_pass %>" },
    context: document.body,
    error: function() { 
      alert('There was an error!');
    },
    success: function() {
      alert('Page sent');
    },
    jsonp: 'jsonp'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935615/how-to-handle-httpstatuscode-correctly), I think you need to remove your success function if you are going to try to handle the status codes directly.

Are you trying to use the statuscodes option like this:

```
statusCode: {
    200:function() { alert("200"); },
    201:function() { alert("201"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [instapaper doco](http://www.instapaper.com/api/simple#jsonp), the parameter specifying the jsonp callback is supposed to be called "jsonp", whereas jQuery defaults it to "callback". You can override this by specifying the "jsonp" option:

```
$("#instapaper").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'jsonp',  // <---------------------NEW BIT HERE
        url:'http://www.instapaper.com/api/add',
        data: {"url": ref , "username": "<%= current_user.instapaper_user %>", "password": "<%= current_user.instapaper_pass %>" },
        context: document.body,
        error: function() { 
          alert('There was an error!');
        },
        success: function() {
          alert('Page sent');
        },
      })
    });
```

See the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.